# c# tcp not working outside intranet

Tags: c#, tcp, ip

Server :

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("90.181.x.xxx"), 23466));

        socket.Listen(1);
        Socket accepteddata = socket.Accept();
        data = new byte[accepteddata.SendBufferSize]; 6
        int j = accepteddata.Receive(data);
        byte[] adata = new byte[j];
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            adata[i] = data[i];
        string dat = Encoding.Default.GetString(adata);
        MessageBox.Show(dat);
```

And client:

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            s.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("90.181.x.xxx"), 23466);
            string q = "It work";
            byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(q);
            s.Send(data);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

The problem is when my friend connect to it he gets error.Yes I have port forwarded.I have set up like this Internal/External port start/end to 23466 and ip address to 192.168.1.1

Comment: The IP of your server is most likely not 192.168.1.1, that's usually your router's address. Type `ipconfig /all` in the command prompt to find your machine's IP address. I'm also not quite certain that you can bind to the public IP address. Please explain more about your network configuration.

Comment: If I type ipconfig / all I got 192.168.1.1 as my ip address.My public ip is 90.181.0.0 know from http://www.whatismypublicip.com/.

Comment: I suggest you test your Server and client separately with a 3rd program. HW group's Hercules does a good job. Combine it with Sysinternals TcpView.

Answer (score 0):

this line here:

```
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("90.181.x.xxx"), 23466));
```

should be:

```
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 23466));
```

Of course you can bind to a specific IP address but it shouldn't be hard coded. "IPAddress.Any" should bind the socket to all addresses on the local machine. The problem you are having is you can't bind to the address of another machine(router).

also, does this code even compile? what does the '6' do?

```
data = new byte[accepteddata.SendBufferSize]; 6
```

The code is weird anyhow. After running the server try opening the command prompt and type "telnet localhost 23466" see if it opens a connection. Your friend or you, doesn't matter can also do "telnet 90.181.x.x 23466"

Make sure you close your sockets when you're finished with them.